# How to change a thermostat on a 2007 Pontiac G6

Tags: pontiac, diy, thermostat

Is it difficult?  How do I know the exact location? Just purchased a replacement but I want to make sure I'm opening up the right compartment.

3.5L V-6

---

This is a picture of what I believe it is. 
[image]

Comment: What you have pictured it the coolant vent pipe.

Answer (score 4):

No that's not the location. It's in the thermostat housing (attached to the engine) that the outlet radiator hose attaches too. This hose runs from the right side (passenger side) of the radiator to the engine.

1. Drain the cooling system
2. Remove the air cleaner outlet duct
3. Remove the radiator outlet hose from the thermostat housing
   [image]
4. Remove the bolt and bolt/stud holding the housing

[image]

5. Remove the thermostat
6. Clean the gasket surfaces
7. Install new thermostat
8. Install new gasket, with gasket sealer if you prefer.
9. Install in the reverse order, Making sure not to over torque the bolts. Spec is 10 N.m (89 inch pounds) or about 7 foot pounds. IE snug or you'll strip the threads out of the block.
10. Fill with 50/50 DEX-COOL and distilled water.

[Picture Source](http://www.2carpros.com/questions/2007-pontiac-g6-thermostat)

Comment: The upper radiator hose attaches to what's in the picture. Can't figure out where the housing is

Comment: @munale That's the inlet hose you are looking at. The thermostat is in the outlet hose. Just to the sideof the oil filter and above the AC compressor

Answer (score 1):

I never located the thermostat but opening up the inlet house and putting back seemed to clear some air out and now it works fine

Comment: Was it different that the pictures I posted?

Comment: It appears so. Or maybe it's just too far down for me to see