# GM 3.5L V6, what is this coolant intake part called?

Tags: coolant-leak

I am refering to the black plastic piece with the two bolts. The o-ring in the block has failed and is leaking. I cannot figure out what the part is called, therefore I am having a hard time finding the correct part to reorder.  [image]

Comment: You know what that tube is for coming out of it?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the year/model of the vehicle in question?

Comment: related..? https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/14711/15036

Comment: It's a 2007 Malibu LTZ 3.5L v6. The tube coming out of it is the coolant intake pipe. It goes across the engine to a hose,then to the reservoir. I can't find that part on any cooling diagrams. It looks like that engine is common in Pontiac G6's of the same era.  There is an oring in it that has begun leaking.

Comment: I borrowed that 'related'  picture because it was better than my own